# How to load several images in the same place

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I have created an html document that uses javascript to connect to xml and get the name of a picture to load using this CSS :

```css
#container {
 width:800px;
}
#left {
    top:10%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    left:30px;
}
#right {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 300px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

And this code:

```js
var TestP = new Array();

function loadImg(n){

TestP[n] = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[n].textContent;
var img = document.createElement('img');
alert(TestP[n]);
img.src = TestP[n];


alert(n);
alert(TestP[n]);
document.getElementById('right').appendChild(img);
```

A part of the HTML :

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="loadImg(1)">Part 1</a></li>
```

The thing is when I first click on the link, everything works well, but when I click another time, I will get two images, each at a different position. I want to have the second image take the exact same place, beeing on top of the first one.

Comment: did you try removing the existing one and loading new one in the placeholder?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elem = document.getElementById( 'right' );
child = elem.firstChild;
if ( child )
  elem.replaceChild( img, child );
else
  elem.appendChild( img );
```

Comment: IT didn't work. they are saying firstChild is not a function!

Comment: that means you have to remove the '()', so it will be elem.firstChild;

Answer (score 1):

don't create a new image, but replace the src attribute.

first give the image an id, so you can find it:

```
<img id="myimage" src="..."/>
```

changing it goes like this:

```
document.getElementById("myimage").src = "...new source...";
```

another option:

```
var TestP = new Array();

function loadImg(n) {
    TestP[n] = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[n].textContent;
    var myImage = document.getElementById("myimage");
    if(myImage != null) {
        myImage.parentNode.removeChild(myImage);
    }
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = TestP[n];
    img.id = "myimage";
    document.getElementById('right').appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: I am not using the img tab, i am using appendChild

Comment: If you append a new image, you'll have to remove the previous one. You could first check if you already appended one (by giving it an id and checking if it's there). If you already apended one, remove it and append a new one. If you didn't append one yet, just append one.

Comment: Could you please help me out more and give me the code that could help in accordance to my written code?

Comment: I edited my post; I hope it's bugfree. All I did was check if there is an image; if there is one, I remove it before appending a new one. To be able to check if it's there I give it an id ("myimage") when creating one.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want *one* image, of which you change the URL each time.

Define in your HTML:

```
<img id="image">
```

and use in JavaScript:

```
var TestP = []; // cleaner way for creating an array

function loadImg(n) {
  TestP[n] = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[n].textContent;

  document.getElementById('image').src = TestP[n];
}
```

Also note that HTML5 introduces some semantics, one of which being binding event handlers through JavaScript instead of through HTML.

Comment: I don't create an image tab, i am using appendChild

Comment: @ELias Rahme: If you're appending images, you'll end up with several of them next to each other... You only want one image, so you don't want to append - could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

well, you are doing it with .appendChild(). then you call it again and it appends second child. so, you have two options. before you append the second image, remove the old one, OR, just replace it.

Comment: Having the code written above, please tell me how can i do it

Comment: add img.setAttribute('id', 'some id'); .. now, you can call the element by document.getElementById('some id') and remove it, or change its attribute src to some new src

Comment: I knw it's a hand full, but may i please ask you to write down the code in according to my code..i'm really new and i guess i'm messing up..thanks in advance